# Trouble defining a generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I have been struggling for some time trying to define a generic interface, but I fail to
achieve what I want. The following is a simplified example of the problem.

Let's say I have a generic *Message* class

```
public class Message<T> {

    private T content;

    public void setContent(T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public T getContent() {
        return content;
    }

}
```

and then I want to define an interface for transfering things:

```
public interface Transfer<Message<T>> {

    public void send(Message message);

}
```

The problem is that the compiler does not accept this, and always complains about
the second '<' character, no matter what variations I try.
How do I specify this interface so that it is bound to a generic type (based on Message)
and also have access to the parameterized type?

My plan was to use this interface like the following:

```
public class Carrier<Message<T>> implements Transfer<Message<T>> {

    public void send(Message message) {
        T content = message.getContent();
        print(content);
    }

    public static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println("The string equals '" + s + "'");
    }

    public static void print(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("The integer equals " + i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Carrier<Message<String>> stringCarrier = new Carrier<Message<String>>();
        Message<String> stringMessage = new Message<String>("test");
        stringCarrier.send(stringMessage);

        Carrier<Message<Integer>> integerCarrier = new Carrier<Message<Integer>>();
        Message<Integer> integerMessage = new Message<Integer>(123);
        integerCarrier.send(integerMessage);
    }
}
```

I have done some searching and reading (among other things [Angelika's generics faq](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/)), but I am not able to tell if this is not possible or if I am doing it wrong.

**Update 2009-01-16**: Removed the original usage of "Thing" instead of "Message< T >" (which was used because with that I was able to compile without getting syntax errors on the interface).

Comment: So is this question resolved or not? It looks like Jon Skeet figured it out, but you didn't mark his answer as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like you want:

```
public class Carrier<Thing extends Message<Foo>, Foo>
    implements Transfer<Thing>
```

That way the compiler will know that `thing` is a `Message<Foo>` and will therefore have a  getContent() method.

You'll need to use it as:

```
Carrier<Message<String>, String>
```

But you've currently got a bit of a disconnect. You're implementing `Transfer<Thing>` but you're trying to use `thing` as if it's a `Message<Thing>` look at your `send` method - you're calling it with a String and an Integer. Those classes don't have `getContent()` methods.

I suspect you should actually be implementing `Transfer<Message<Thing>>` instead of `Transfer<Thing>`

Comment: Yes, bingo! I want to define the interface as "Transfer<Message<Thing>>" and that was my first approach. However, when I try that the compiler always gives syntax error on the second < no matter what variant of that I try. So using just "Transfer<Thing>" was the only way I got something to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you solve your generics problem, your code will not compile because you do not have a print method that takes a type of T as a parameter.

I believe you will have to do instance of checks if you want the functionality you are looking for.  So, I don't think you gain any value from the generic type in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to specify T for the class, and then use Message< T > for your argument/return types.

```
public interface Transfer<T> {
    public void send(Message<T> message);
}
```

The reason you don't use Message< T > is because you're providing the 'this is a message' context in your arguments and return types.